# Docker container which runs Express js service does not find MySQL database which is also in it's own docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, express, docker-compose

I am sorry in advance if I don't explain the problem good enough.
I created a custom Docker image containing a MySQL database, which works fine. I tested it out and when I connect to it from my main operating system with Express everything seems to work. The problems begin when I put the Express js API in it's own container, then I get a connection error on host. (I tried both with 127.0.0.0 and name-of-container) as hosts in my connection object.

**This is my database.js**

```js
module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'db',
user: 'root',
password: 'root',
database: 'footballplayers'
})
```

**This is my docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

 db:
  image: mysql_db
  container_name: db
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 3306:3306
  expose: 
   - 3306 
  networks:
   - whole-application 
  
 product-service:
  image: football-api
  build: .
  depends_on:
   - db
  ports:
   - 3000:4000
  networks:
   - whole-application 

networks:
 whole-application:
```

**This is the error I get by running the Docker compose**

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)

errno: -3001,

#0 5.430   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',

#0 5.430   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',

#0 5.430   hostname: 'db',

#0 5.430   fatal: true

If anyone knows how to fix this problem I would greatly appreciate anyone's input.